# Branch link can contain live key

Tags: branch.io

In our iOS app, if the iPhone is disconnected while generating an app link with Branch, the SDK generates this kind of link:

```
http://address.com/a/key_live_randomsecretlivekey?%24identity_id=...
```

Is that a security hole? Shouldn't that key be only known to us as the developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not a security issue. Branch Keys are intended to be publicly accessible. It is the corresponding Branch Secret that needs to be protected.

When the Branch SDK is unable to communicate with the Branch back end it will not be able to create a Branch link. It therefore creates a [dynamic link](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/other-ways/ios/#appending-query-parameters) that will result in the creation of a link when it is tapped (the dynamic link does not exist on the back end - it has a list of all the required query parameters for creating the desired link). This allows users to share content even when they have no Internet connectivity.